# PHP Loop information in a loop from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am creating a page that displays player details and have the information pulling through fine. I also have a joining table that pulls single records from another table for nationality fine so joins arent the problem.

But now completely stuck on how to loop through data that is already looping.

in my players.php class, I have a function pulling through all the information I need and can display fine on the frontend.

```
function getById($id)
{
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT *, nationalities.nationality FROM players 
            LEFT JOIN nationalities ON players.nationality = nationalities.id 
            WHERE players.id = :id";

    $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $st->execute();

    $row = $st->fetch();
    $conn = null;

    if ($row) return new Players($row);
}

function getList($numRows = 1000000, $order = "lastname DESC")
{
    $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, lastname AS lastname FROM players
            ORDER BY " . ($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();

    $list = array();

    while ($row = $st->fetch())
    {
        $player = new Players($row);
        $list[] = $player;
    }

    //Now get the total number of players that matched the criteria
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";

    $totalRows = $conn->query($sql)->fetch();
    $conn = null;

    return (array("results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0]));
}
```

**My challenge is that a player can have multiple positions, not just 1 displaying?** How do I achieve this I've tried while looping after this with SQL but it just doesnt seem to be working in any which way I approach it. My tables are:

```
**players**
id, firstname, lastname ...



**positions**
id, position

**player_positions**
player_id, position_id
```

Querying like this, with the below dataset:

```
SELECT positions.position, players.firstname, players.lastname
FROM positions 
LEFT JOIN player_positions ON positions.id = player_positions.position_id
LEFT JOIN players ON player_positions.players_id = players.id
WHERE players_id = :id
```

.

```
position, firstname, lastname
RWB, Lewis, Robinson
CB, Lewis, Robinson
```

My first loop is going through the players and retrieving data fine, but now i need it to loop in that loop of data over this dataset and store it as positions and then be able to display it on frontend :(

Any help or pointers on doing such a thing would be great

Comment: I don't get the exact point where you get a problem. Do you have some problems while trying to perform your last query from inside the loop?

Comment: Is your intention to group or order the results in the `$list` by player?

Comment: So I will loop through the initial query and retrieve all players and their informaiton but a player may have more than one position... i.e. Lewis Robinson may be associated to CB, RB and LB - does that make sense? 

and thanks for coming back anyway haha

Answer (score 0):

I would group the positions by player, and then use a double loop to display the players positions.

```
function getList($numRows = 1000000, $order = "lastname DESC")
{
    $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, lastname AS lastname, id AS id FROM players
            ORDER BY " . ($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();

    $list = array();

    while ($row = $st->fetch())
    {
        $id = $row[2];
        $player = new Players($row);
        if(!isset($list[$id])) list[$id] = array(); 
        $list[$id][] = $player;
    }

    //Now get the total number of players that matched the criteria
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";

    $totalRows = $conn->query($sql)->fetch();
    $conn = null;

    return (array("results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0]));
}

//Used like this (just an example for the loops):

$list = getList();

foreach($list as $id => $positions) {
    echo $positions[0]->playerName."<br>";
    foreach($positions as $player) {
        //Output
        echo print_r($player, true)."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: okay so from my understanding this won't work either.... forgive me if i'm just interpretting this wrong... but i was using <?php echo $player->id?> to pull the information out about the player... which seemed logical as  I am using that data. the above seems to change this to $id so the player is now just an $id which i assume is right. but then $positions as $player changes that i'll give it a whirl with $positions as $position ad see if this will work - its another route to try so i thank you